# Want to connect to Azure Windows Virtual Desktop in browser using c#?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have connected to Remote Desktop/Virtual Network using Myrtille C# (just like Chrome Remote Desktop). I want to connect Azure Windows Virtual Desktop using C#. The concept is to connect to Azure Windows Virtual Desktop in the browser using C#. On the browser add required fields like IP address, Port, User Name, and Password, and after the button click, wants to connect to Windows Virtual Desktop. Is there any code available to did this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I initially went through the official documentation and looked online for C# examples without any success.  I then looked further into the differences between Azure Virtual Machines and Azure Windows Virtual Desktop.

The connection process with Azure Windows Virtual Desktop requires more in the way of authentication than providing a simple User Name and Password as you would with a virtual machine.  This is the [client connection sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/network-connectivity#client-connection-sequence):

> 1. Using supported Windows Virtual Desktop client user subscribes to the Windows Virtual Desktop Workspace
> 2. Azure Active Directory authenticates the user and returns the token used to enumerate resources available to a user
> 3. Client passes token to the Windows Virtual Desktop feed subscription service
> 4. Windows Virtual Desktop feed subscription service validates the token
> 5. Windows Virtual Desktop feed subscription service passes the list of
>    available desktops and RemoteApps back to the client in the form of
>    digitally signed connection configuration
> 6. Client stores the connection configuration for each available
>    resource in a set of .rdp files
> 7. When a user selects the resource to connect, the client uses the
>    associated .rdp file and establishes the secure TLS 1.2 connection
>    to the closest Windows Virtual Desktop gateway instance and passes
>    the connection information
> 8. Windows Virtual Desktop gateway validates the request and asks the
>    Windows Virtual Desktop broker to orchestrate the connection
> 9. Windows Virtual Desktop broker identifies the session host and uses
>    the previously established persistent communication channel to
>    initialize the connection
> 10. Remote Desktop stack initiates the TLS 1.2 connection to the same
>     Windows Virtual Desktop gateway instance as used by the client
> 11. After both client and session host connected to the gateway, the
>     gateway starts relaying the raw data between both endpoints, this
>     establishes the base reverse connect transport for the RDP
> 12. After the base transport is set, the client starts the RDP
>     handshake

There's additional reading you can do if you'd like to learn more about RDP for Windows Virtual Desktop, but it doesn't look like Myrtille will work for what you are trying to accomplish.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-virtual-desktop/announcing-public-preview-of-rdp-shortpath-transport-for-windows/m-p/1889372

[image: Windows Virtual Desktop technical diagram]